# How to migrate from xp-dev to github?

Tags: github

I have a repository in xp-dev that I want to move to github.  I have no experience in xp-dev but I do know github.  How would I migrate that repository to github?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be to clone your xp-dev repo, and a remote to GitHub and push it there:

```
git clone --mirror <xp-dev-url>
cd xpdevRepo
git remote add github newGitHubRepoUrl
git push -f --tags github refs/heads/*:refs/heads/*
```

That supposes you have created an empty repo on GitHub first.